# Does each conditional statement have to be enclosed in parenthesis in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements, syntax-error

I was writing a program in python using pandas where there were multiple conditional statements.

`top_oceania_wines = reviews[(reviews.country == 'Australia'|reviews.country=='New Zealand')& reviews.points>=95]`

On running this I got syntax error. I wanted the `or` operation before the end so I used the parenthesis but what is wrong with the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
top_oceania_wines = reviews[(reviews.country == 'Australia')|(reviews.country=='New Zealand')& (reviews.points>=95)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
top_oceania_wines = reviews[((reviews.country=='Australia') | (reviews.country=='New Zealand')) & (reviews.points>=95)]
```

or

```
top_oceania_wines = reviews[(reviews.country=='Australia') | ((reviews.country=='New Zealand') & (reviews.points>=95))]
```